# Measure theory problems.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove or disprove the following:

a)If $\mathscr A$ is a $σ$-Algebra on $Ω$ then {$Ω$ \ $A$ : $A$ element of $\mathscr A$} too.

b)A $σ$-Algebra with 3 elements exists.

c)A measure $μ$ on $P(\mathbb R)$ with $μ$({x}}=$1$ exists.

---

a) Isn't this equal to Ω \ $\mathscr A$? If so then this is the second property of a $σ$-Algebra.

b) Ω={1,2,3}, $\mathscr A$={{1},{2},{3}} is right?

c) I don't know I just know that for a Lebesgue-Measure $μ$({x}} is equal to $0$. Don't know if any measure exists that can satify c).

Comment: a) You seem to be mixing up what's going. A $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, it is not itself a subset of $\Omega$. Thus the expression $\Omega \backslash \mathscr{A}$ has no real meaning in this context (though of course it is just the empty set).
b) I can tell you $\mathscr{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Hint: try taking a certain countable union of its elements. Is this new set an element of the $\sigma$-algebra?
c) I'm guessing $x$ is a fixed point of $\mathbb{R}$. Try from the most basic measures that assume no extra structure on the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: To prove a), you need to test that $\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \backslash \mathscr{A} = \{ \Omega \backslash A ~|~ A \in \mathscr{A} \}$ satisfies the axioms of a $\sigma$-algebra. What are these? How would you test them? To clarify a little more with c), the Lebesgue measure will *not* do. Instead, think of very basic measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) A $\sigma$-algebra is stable under complementation, hence $\{\Omega\setminus A,A\in\mathcal A\}=\mathcal A$ (it cannot be equal to $\Omega\setminus \mathcal A$, because $\mathcal A$ is a *class of subsets of $\Omega$*, while $\Omega$ is a set.

b) Your $\mathcal A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra (it should at least contain $\Omega$). If $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra with more than two elements, there is $A\in\mathcal A$ which is neither the whole set nor empty. But this is also the case for $\Omega \setminus A$.

c) Consider the counting measure (which assigns to each sets its number of elements if the set if finite, and $+\infty$ otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

a) You need to show that ${\cal B} = \{ \Omega \setminus A | A \in {\cal A} \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. This is a straightforward verification using the definitions.

b) A $\sigma$-algebra must be closed under complementation, so, for example,  the set $\{2,3\}$ must be in ${\cal A}$ above. So the ${\cal A}$ above cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra.

In general a $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal A}$ must contain $\emptyset, \Omega$, so $|{\cal A}| \ge 2$. If ${\cal A}$ contains another set $A$, then it must also contain the complement. What does that say about $|{\cal A}|$?

c) The Lebesgue measure cannot work, as any point has measure $0$. Try  letting $\mu A = \begin{cases} 1, &  x \in A \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and check that it satisfies the definition.